# Kotlin - An Elegant Way to Expose a Mutable List as an Immutable List

Tags: kotlin

I have a class where I want to be able to modify a list internally, but externally I want the list to be immutable; for example...

```kotlin
class Foo {
    val items: List<String> get() = mutableItems
    private val mutableItems: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
}
```

Is there a nicer way to express this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit: The feature originally described below has evolved into the *explicit backing fields* feature, which is currently prototyped in the K2 compiler. With [explicit backing fields](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/explicit-backing-fields-re/proposals/explicit-backing-fields.md), the syntax would be:

```
val items: List<String>
    field = mutableListOf()
```

---

Original answer:

No, but they have something in the works that might appear in a future version of Kotlin. The suggested syntax would look something like this:

```
private val items: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
    public get(): List<String>
```

[This was presented by the language design lead in a talk about possible future features of Kotlin.](https://youtu.be/0FF19HJDqMo?t=1313)

To be a bit pedantic, you are exposing a read-only List, not an immutable one.

Comment: I'm curious - What's the difference between a read-only list and an immutable list?

Comment: Immutable implies that it’s contents cannot possibly change. If it were a promise of immutability, the outside class that gets this List property would have a guarantee that it could iterate the list multiple times and always see the exact same results. But it’s actually only read-only to the outside classes. They can’t expect it’s contents to never change based on the interface alone.

Comment: Mmmm.  Or to put it another way: ‘read-only’ = can't be changed _through that reference_; ‘immutable’ = can't be changed _at all_.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I still struggle with read-only vs. immutable. For example, what's stopping someone from using reflection to peek into an immutable list and modify it?

Comment: @MatthewLayton Nothing can stop reflection from breaking all kinds of rules. Reflection can ignore `private` keywords and change almost anything. Using reflection is generally understood to be operating in a danger zone, especially if using it on classes that are not under your own source control. With reflection, nothing that has, directly or un-directly, non-const properties (or non-final fields in Java) can truly be called read-only **or** immutable, but those terms come with the assumption of no reflection being involved.

Comment: As of Kotlin 1.9.0, the syntax you mention has not been implemented yet. If you want to be notified when (and if) this gets added, you can [track the issue on JetBrains' issue tracker, YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-14663/Support-having-a-public-and-a-private-type-for-the-same-property).

Comment: @FWDekker, this feature evolved into *explicit backing fields". It's already implemented if you switch to the K2 compiler. See my updated answer above--it has a link to the KEEP for it.

Comment: Oh my, somehow I had skipped over that part! Thank you for the clarification! (I cannot edit my previous comment anymore, but I won't delete it to preserve context.)

Answer (score 0):

A similar example can be found in the Kotlin documentation under "Backing properties" (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#backing-properties).

They have a private variable `_table` type of `Map<String, Int>?` but it is exposed outside as `Map<String, Int>`.

```kotlin
private var _table: Map<String, Int>? = null
public val table: Map<String, Int>
    get() {
        if (_table == null) {
            _table = HashMap() // Type parameters are inferred
        }
        return _table ?: throw AssertionError("Set to null by another thread")
    }
```

In your case you can do something like this:

```kotlin
class Foo {
    private val _items: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()

    val items: List<String>
        get() = _items

    // ...
    fun addItem(item: String) = _items.add(item)
}
```

or

```kotlin
class Foo {
    private val _items: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()

    val items: List<String> = _items

    // ...
    fun addItem(item: String) = _items.add(item)
}
```

.

Is it "An Elegant Way" to use a private property with underscore sign?

Answer (score -2):

You can do something like this:

```
private val items : MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
fun items() : List<String> = items
```

When you want to access your items externally just use `items()` function. In internal usage work with list directly

Comment: That's worse. All this does is change the public semantics from a property to a function.

Comment: @MatthewLayton Yes I know, but there is more readable, and you should not have two variable for the array.

Comment: Sorry, again I would argue that neither of those points is true. This is less readable due to the change in semantics. Functions and their names should where possible and in most cases be verbs (do, get, filter, append, create, etc.). There aren't two ~variables~ properties for the _same_ collection, since one refers to a collection which may be modified internally, and one refers to a read-only collection which may not be modified externally. The answer given by @Tenfour04 is what I was looking for, albeit not implemented, yet. Beyond that, I'm afraid we will have to agree to disagree.