# Kotlin backing property in Android ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin

Was just wondering, why is it better to use backing property for MutableLiveData, instead of just exposing getter function that returns the MutableLiveData property as live data. For example:
Why this code

```
private val _registeredDevicesObservable: MediatorLiveData<List<Data>> = MediatorLiveData()
val registeredDevicesObservable: LiveData<List<Data>> = _registeredDevicesObservable
```

is better or more acceptable than this one

```
private val _registeredDevicesObservable: MediatorLiveData<List<Data>> = MediatorLiveData()
fun registeredDevicesObservable(): LiveData<List<Data>> = _registeredDevicesObservable
```

As also when this getter function is keeping the LiveData immutability and keeps me from having that little annoying underscore syntax when accessing the property inside the view model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just less idiomatic in the language to use a function that simply returns an already-available object. You're free to do it any way you like, but if others have to work with your code, it will be easier to understand and work with if you follow general conventions.

There isn't as strong a convention about whether the backing property should have a leading underscore in the name, so if you don't like it, don't use it.

One reason to stick with these conventions is there is a [proposed upcoming language feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66923391/506796) to allow you to do this without a backing property, and so if you're following the conventions, it will be very easy to update your code to eliminate the backing property.

Comment: Also the java byte code that is formed is basically a function too right as in if we are using `get()` for some property. The Java byte code will have that `get()` function for that property.

Comment: Yes, and if you use `get() = ` instead of just `=`, the property won't even generate a backing field.

Comment: So if I am correct in this assumption using `get() = ` overall must have a less memory imprint that creating a separate function and exposing livedata that way.

Comment: It would be equivalent. The property with custom getter is a method in bytecode, just like the separate function would be.