# ViewModel function implementation with MutableLiveData or use directly a LiveData?

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I have a function `getAdressSuggestions` who return a list of `AddressResult`

I wonder what is the best implementation between this two :

The first one is with a MutableLiveData we have inside the viewModel this :

```
private val _adressState = MutableLiveData<AddressSearchUIState>()
val adressState: LiveData<AddressSearchUIState>
    get() = _adressState
```

The `AddressSearchUIState` is a sealed class who contains a data class named Success

```
sealed class AddressSearchUIState {
    data class Success(val suggestions: List<AddressResult>) : AddressSearchUIState()
}
```

And this is the function inside the viewModel

```
fun getAdressSuggestions(text: String) =
    viewModelScope.launch(dispatcher) {
        val result = geocodingRepository.predictAddresses(text.lowercase())
        _adressState.postValue(AddressSearchUIState.Success(result))
    }
```

We get the result from the repository and post the value in the `MutableLiveData` `_adressState`

And inside the fragment I create an observer like this

```
viewModel.adressState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { adresses ->
        if (adresses is InformationsViewModel.AddressSearchUIState.Success) {
            //Do things
        }
    }
```

**I can now do it another way with less code and LiveData** like this :

```
fun getAdressSuggestions(text: String) = liveData {
    viewModelScope.launch(dispatcher) {
        emit(geocodingRepository.predictAddresses(text.lowercase()))
    }
}
```

and observe it in Fragment like this

```
viewModel.getAdressSuggestions(it).observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { adresses ->
                //Do things
}
```

For me the second option is lighter and better but am I missing something ?

In which use case the first option will be better to implement ?

Comment: This question is opinion-based so likely to get closed. IMO, returning a LiveData from a function is a bloated and hacky way to expose what would traditionally be a function that just takes a callback parameter. Since your LiveData is only returning a single value, it’s confusing/convoluted that you have to `observe` it to wait for that sole result. I would just make it a suspend function and directly return the result. The caller can use its own scope so it will have proper cancellation of the task.

Comment: But the first way with MutableLiveData is likely more appropriate because it will preserve what was fetched if the activity is destroyed and recreated, such as after a screen rotation. If I were doing it the first way, I’d name the function “update” instead of “get” since the function isn’t directly returning something, but rather is updating the LiveData with the most put to date value.

Comment: I understand your point but this : " I would just make it a suspend function and directly return the result "  It's a thing I would like to know if its good or bad practice.
For me I dont find it really clean because I prefer to use the viewModel lifecycle and I don't like to call suspend function directly inside the fragment/Activity file

Comment: The custom getter in the first version seems unnecessary. You could just write `val adressState: LiveData<AddressSearchUIState> = _addressState`. As for when the first version is "better" (necessary); consider a scenario where you both want to return the value to your fragment *and* use it as an input to e.g. a `MediatorLiveData` within your ViewModel.

Comment: @Vodet That’s why I said I think the first way with the mutable live data is more likely the better way. Then you are using the lifecycle of the view model so the task isn’t wasted and restarted during a screen rotation. With a suspend function or your way of returning a newly created live data, the task result is cancelled or wasted during a screen rotation. But for the first way to avoid restarting after a screen rotation, you might need to do some sort of check before updating it. I’d personally put the `text` parameter in a private live data or flow, and expose a second live data or flow

Comment: based on that text source as a map transformation. Then it won’t restart so long as the activity passes the same parameter.

Comment: Note, having a private mutable live data that is publicly read-only will soon be cleaner to write: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66923228/kotlin-an-elegant-way-to-expose-a-mutable-list-as-an-immutable-list/66923391#66923391

Comment: Is it usefull to use a sealed class instead of using directly a data class ?
like this  : data class AddressSearchUIState(val suggestions: List<AddressResult>) : AddressSearchUIState()
Normally I'm using sealed class when I have multiple class inside like Loading / Success / Error